# Convert Byte Array into List Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using this piece of code to convert List into byte array but again I want to convert to this data into List how it is possible.

```
List<String> stringlist = new List<String>();
stringlist.Add("Oye Oye");
stringlist.Add("Hello hello");
byte[] byteArr = stringlist.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because you lost information where one string ends and another one starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it isn't possible, because you have no way to tell where a string ends and where the next one starts. It would be possible by using a separator (the character \0 is often used to indicate the end of a string):

```
List<String> stringlist = new List<String>();
stringlist.Add("Oye Oye");
stringlist.Add("Hello hello");
byte[] byteArr = stringlist.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + '\0').ToArray();
```

You can then retrieve your list by using the `Split` method:

```
var stringList = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArr, 0, byteArr.Length).Split('\0');
```

But overall I don't think it's a good idea. Depending on what you need, I'd rather recommend to use the `DataContractSerializer` to convert your array to bytes:

```
var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<string>));

byte[] byteArr;

using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, stringlist);
    byteArr = ms.ToArray();
}
```

And to convert it back:

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArr))
{
    stringlist = (Sserializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Comment: Can We convert List of objects that contain objects of Line and Images by using Serialization?